# print hidden div of visibility:collapse to pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I am using jspdf to print html elements to pdf. If the div section is not hidden, the pdf prints to view the contents of the html elements. When the section of the html element is hidden or collapse, it prints a blank pdf document. Here is the snippets

```
function bookPDF() {
          // Get the element.
          var element = document.getElementById('bookPDF');
        var opt = {
          margin:       1,
          filename:     'book.pdf',
          image:        { type: 'png', quality: 0.98 },
          html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
          jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
        };

        html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

        }
```

here is the html elements shown

```
 <a onclick="bookPDF()" class="ui button"> 
          <i class="download icon"></i>&nbsp;Book</a>

<div id="bookPDF" 
 style="visibility:collapse max-width:60%; margin:0 auto; background: #fff;border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;" 
 class="table-wrapper ui basic segment">

  <h1 class="ui dividing header center aligned">
    Books collections
  </h1>
  ......//more content but pdf prints does not print
</div
```

how do I get around this... printing the pdf even when hidden with css element

Answer (score 0):

You can try and temporarily make it visible then hide it after the print as in:

```
function bookPDF() {
  // Get the element.
  var element = document.getElementById("bookPDF");
  var opt = {
    margin: 1,
    filename: "book.pdf",
    image: { type: "png", quality: 0.98 },
    html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
    jsPDF: { unit: "in", format: "letter", orientation: "portrait" }
  };

  element.style.visibility = "visible"; // <== here 

  html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

  element.style.visibility = "hidden"; // <== and here 
}
```